# "Error starting tab capture" when trying to capture tab audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to capture the audio of an active tab using a chrome extension. My code injects a content script into the given tab and then uses `chrome.tabs` to send the stream id to that content script.

However, I get an error when I try to begin capturing the tab's audio, which is:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error starting tab capture`. I should have sufficient privleges (`activeTab`, etc...) so I am unsure what is causing this error.

My code is as follows: (This is for the content script)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req,sender,res) => {
    // Stringify is a function that returns a string given an object, this doesn't cause the error
    message = stringify(req.command)
    if (message == "captureStream") {      
        console.log(req.data.streamId)  
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: false,
            audio: true,
            audio: {
                mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: "tab",
                    chromeMediaSourceId: req.data.streamId  
                }
            }
        }), (stream) => {
            const output = new AudioContext();
            const source = output.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            source.connect(output.destination);
        }
    

    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You cant use stringify for your strings. you have to use string()

Answer (score 0):

Add the `tabCapture` permission and specify `consumerTabId`. For example:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async tab => {
    const streamId = await chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({consumerTabId: tab.id})
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {data: {streamId: streamId}})
})
```